# Fetch AD Groups Without Parents Via C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, active-directory, ldap

I'm looking into fetching a list of Active Directory groups within an OU which have no parent groups using C# .NET.

I found a PowerShell command which looked hopeful, Get-QADGroup (http://wiki.powergui.org/index.php/Get-QADGroup), but I couldn't find a parameter that would filter for groups that have no parent groups.

I could iterate through the groups in the OU and check if each has a parent group or not, but I'd like to consider alternatives. Is this possible through an LDAP query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply check if `memberOf` is not populated.

The LDAP filter would be `(&(objectCategory=group)(!memberOf=*))`.  The following PowerShell example would return all groups that are not members of any other groups.

```
 Import-Module ActiveDirectory
 $ldapFilter = '(&(objectCategory=group)(!(memberOf=*)))'
 Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter $ldapFilter
```